# yii2 joinwith non-primary key

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I have 2 tables books and categories and want join to books categories

```
LEFT JOIN categories ON books.category_id = category.id

Books::find()
            ->joinWith('category', true, 'LEFT JOIN');
```

How I can set manually colums `books.category_id = category.id` because it's not primary keys.

Comment: What do you mean by "because it's not primary keys" ??? Show us your `category` relation in `Books` model.

Comment: @soju I not have created foreign keys

Comment: Well, I don't see the problem... Show us your `category` relation in `Books` model...

Comment: You can definitely join anything to anything, there's a parameter that goes into the `ON` part of the `JOIN` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the relation to your Books model e.g. (because i don't know your relation type i have added 2 normal examples)

```
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']);
}

public function getCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']);
}
```

Then you should be able to use your join. 
But i don't know if the following issue (see link) is still legit (as i always have primary keys added)

[Unable to define relationship on table missing primary key](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6365)

this tutorial link also help
[yii2 select-query-joins](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/select-query-joins/)